# How Often Do Keys Get Stuck with MacBook Pro 2017 Butterfly Keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, hardware

I went to a apple store recently and ordered a custom 2017 Macbook Pro with the help of an employee. I was ordering on a demo MacBook Pro when I noticed that the B key was stuck and could not be pressed. This got me suspicious, but I assumed apple has high quality products so I ordered it anyway. In the evening, I did some research and I found out that this a much [bigger problem](https://theoutline.com/post/2402/the-new-macbook-keyboard-is-ruining-my-life?zd=1&zi=iqzlgywz). So big, that apple even as an [official diagnostic page](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT205662) for stuck butterfly keys.

So my question is how often do 2017 MacBook Pros have their keys getting stuck? I would prefer some kind of statistic or results from formal testing. I could only find diagnostics for the problem on the internet.

Comment: Is there an actual problem to solve here?  The question is way to broad, and too opinionated.  Sourcing data from a blog who references "Apple Geniuses" is far from an objective approach.  I would be very hesitant to that blog as some sort of definitive source.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this is still on hold? I feel I have edited the question so that it is very pointed. I don't think I can make this question any more specific: Can someone find me statistics or results from formal testing that is about MacBook pro 2017 butterfly keys getting stuck?

Comment: I'd say 100% if it gets dust on it